# Append base target HTML to Google Maps iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe

I am using Google Maps in an iframe on my client's website and the locations on the map have external links in their descriptions. When the links are clicked, the external website loads within the iframe. I am wanting to figure out a way for the external links to open in a new browser window using jQuery. I have looked into jQuery append() and appending the base target HTML attribute to the head of the iframe tag, but I have been unable to make it work.

Can anyone provide some assistance with this issue?

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: Post some code please.  Are you building the hrefs your self?  If so have you tried target="_blank"?

Comment: yes, can you post some code or post the link to your site? when i click on links in a map in my iframe it opens in a new tab properly, so can't recreate your issue

Comment: The website in question is truenorthrd.com. If you scroll down to the Your Next Neighborhood section, you will see a Google Map displayed in an iframe. Some of the neighbourhoods have shape layers and descriptions. The text links in the descriptions open within the iframe and not in a new window. I have tried using jQuery to append the base target attribute to the head of the iframe, but I have been unsuccessful so far. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get all the a tags iframe and use attr to add a target to each link 
$('a').attr('target','_blank');